# [[[Number]]] does not want to save my [[]] array correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a triple nested array defined in mongoose. When I try to initialize it with a 2 level deep empty array, it adds a third level. See the following code:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const foos = mongoose.model(`FooModel`, new Schema({ numbers: [[[Number]]] }));
const oneFoo = await foos.create({ numbers: [[]] });
console.log(oneFoo.numbers);

Expected: [[]], Actual: [[[]]]
```

The interesting thing is that it doesn't happen with a 2 level deep array:

```
const foos = mongoose.model(`FooModel`, new Schema({ numbers: [[Number]] }));
const oneFoo = await foos.create({ numbers: [] });
console.log(oneFoo.numbers);

Expected: [], Actual: []
```

Any ideas on why this is not working, and is there any workaround ?

Versions:

```
"mongodb": "3.5.4",
"mongoose": "5.9.22",
```

EDIT: This was a bug fixed in `5.9.23`:

- [Release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#5923--2020-07-10)
- [PR](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/9217)

Comment: Have you tried using single empty array from second case or adding some values? Just in case

Comment: adding values definitely works, but I really want to save `[[]]` in database, not something else.

Comment: Are you sure that it should not be `[]`? `[[]]` looks a bit odd as for empty value even though it's supposed to have 3 levels

Comment: Well, actually, it is `[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]` (representing a week) that is transformed to `[[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]]`, not quite the same !

Comment: I see, but I don't get why you would need these empty arrays inside an array when they don't carry any information. Looks like it should be somewhere on a backend side to provide default empty values before return or in a Schema as a default return value if some code requires these empty arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Why:**

Before mongoose v5.9.2(i.e v5.9.1 and below), mongoose would actually behave the way you expect. However, an issue was raised concerning how mongoose handles typecasting for nested arrays([Github Link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8544)), I believe the fix for that issue is what caused the changed behavior you are experiencing.

**The Fix:**

As recommended in the issue thread [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8544#issuecomment-586770774), set the [castNoneArrays option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/documentarraypath.html#documentarraypath_DocumentArrayPath.options) to `false`.

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

mongoose.Schema.Types.Array.options.castNonArrays = false;

const foos = mongoose.model(`FooModel`, new Schema({ numbers: [[[Number]]] }));
const oneFoo = await foos.create({ numbers: [[]] });
console.log(oneFoo.numbers);  // Outputs: [[]]
```

Comment: Awesome findings. Still a bug though, because it should throw a cast error, but it doesn't.